# Can't login after adding configure application cookies

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, cookies

I'm developing Asp.Net Core 3.1 MVC web application with Identity. My login page works fine but after adding the `services.ConfigureApplicationCookie` it not worked as expected and it keeps redirecting me to my local index. I can't figure out what really happen. If I comment this block, everything works as expected.

Here is my ConfigureServices method in **Startup** file

```
 // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
           options.UseSqlServer(
               Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(options => {
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
        })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>()
            .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
            .AddClaimsPrincipalFactory<UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        //.AddDefaultTokenProviders() 
        .AddDefaultUI();

        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie();

        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.Name = ".ExpirationCookie";
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Pages/Account/Login";
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Identity/Pages/Account/AccessDenied"; 
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.Zero;
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            options.ReturnUrlParameter = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.ReturnUrlParameter;
            options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
            {
                OnValidatePrincipal = ValidateAsync.ValidatingAsync
            };
        })
        .Configure<SecurityStampValidatorOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.ValidationInterval = TimeSpan.Zero;
        });

        services.AddSingleton<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
        services.Configure<EmailOptions>(Configuration);
        services.AddHangfire(config => config.UseSqlServerStorage(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddHangfireServer();
        services.AddControllersWithViews(); //?
        services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation(); //?
        services.AddScoped<IExpirationJob, ExpirationJob>();
        services.AddScoped<IReminderJob, EmailReminder>();
        services.AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();
        services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        {
            // Password settings.
            //options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            //options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
            //options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
            //options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
            //options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
            //options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1;
            // Lockout settings.
            //options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            //options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
            //options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;
            // User settings.
            //options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters =
            //    "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+ ";
            //options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.cookieauthenticationoptions.expiretimespan?view=aspnetcore-1.1):

> Controls how much time the cookie will remain valid from the point it is created. The expiration information is in the protected cookie ticket. Because of that an expired cookie will be ignored even if it is passed to the server after the browser should have purged it

In your `ConfigureApplicationCookie`,you set the cookie lifespan to `zero`.

Cookie authtication will never be successfully,you need to change it, like `FromSeconds`,`FromMinutes`,`FromHours`...

```
    //......
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(24);
    //.......
```